# Aligning Button and multiline textblock in Stack panel Silverligh

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Here is the scenarion:

```
---------- ++++++++++++
--Button-- +Text block+
---------- ++++++++++++
```

In WPF is extremely easy with a dock panel. What is the way to achieve this in Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a StackPanel and make its orientation Horizontal.  You can then adjust the vertical and horizontal alignment of the stack panel's children to your needs.

ie:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="High" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Button>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" Width="100" Text="Insert Text Here" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly i was looking for.
Being honest i tried this approach by my own, but it failed. What is fixing it was the setting width property. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DockPanel in Silverlight too, thanks to the [Silverlight toolki](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)t.

After installing the toolkit you can add the following namespace in your XAML:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

Then in your element's attributes add:

```
toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right"
```

Of course change "Right" to: Right, Left, Top, or Bottom as needed.